# How do I detect a checkered texture in an image with open cv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, hsv

Starting from a Minecraft image where the objective is to detect the presence of the chainmail armor, I have used filtering in masks with HSV

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2

detect_state = False

lower_range_chainmail_armor = np.array([75, 80, 100])
upper_range_chainmail_armor = np.array([90, 255, 255])

frameHSV = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

mask_chainmail_armor = cv2.inRange(frameHSV, lower_range_diamond, upper_range_diamond)
    maskdiamondvis = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask= mask_diamond)

'''
#This doesn't work because I dont need compare only with color
if(int(cv2.countNonZero(mask_chainmail_armor)) > 5000):
        print("Detect chainmail armor!")
        detect_state = True
'''
```

The problem is that it is not enough to find the gray color, but it also has to be a kind of checkered texture, as is that image

Original Image:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Binarized image with HSV filter:

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

How to put a variable detection to `True` only when it detects a checkered image like this?

Comment: There is `findChessboardCorners` which can detect checkerboard patterns. It seems to work on the chainmail inventory-icon, but not reliable on images of someone wearing it. Could still be helpful to try it out I think.

Comment: @OliverTale-Yazdi I was thinking of putting a second conditional inside if (int (cv2.countNonZero (mask_chainmail_armor))> 5000): using that function that you say from findChessboardCorners ().
Do you know how to make a conditional that determines whether or not it detects boardCorners?